# 14.04 Dash Home won't load

Tags: 14.04, unity, unity-dash

I just installed 14.04 and when I click on the dash home, nothing displays. The launcher is normal. When I click on the dash, the arrow appears next to the icon signalling it's opened, the launcher becomes transparent, but it displays nothing but my background. No search bar, nothing.

Everything else launches like normal except the dash.

I tried resetting unity, reinstalling unity, made sure that all drivers were installed, redownloaded 14.04 ISO & formatted drive & did a fresh install.

I tried it in another user account as well and it does the same thing.

I tried:

```
sudo apt-get install unity-scope-home
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop^
sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity-lens-* unity-scope-home
```

None of these worked either.

This is my first time using Ubuntu and I'm not sure what to do next.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlGT4.jpg) is an imgur link to the screen I'm seeing as well.

Comment: Are you using an up to date image? Try making sure everything is up to date. apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade.

Comment: Also, does everything work if you boot from the image into a live session?

Comment: I know it seems silly, but may as well give it a try. When the dash "opens," try clicking the maximise button at the top left, as shown in the screenshot.
A fresh reinstall should have solved a software error, though, so, this is probably some weird hardware error...

Comment: Clicking on the maximize button makes minor changes. It only changes the colour of the menu bar from black to grey.

Comment: When I try to run apt-get update I get a permission error.

Comment: When I boot from the image into the trial version, it's giving me the same issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it! I lowered the screen resolution and the Dash reappeared. If only I knew this before I reinstalled 3 times.

Comment: I know it has been a while, but your idea of changing the resolution just helped me out. Obviously I had the same problem using Ubuntu 16.04. I have 2 27" monitors connected. The problem was, that I had rotated 1 monitor by 90° clockwise. Dash does not like that at all. After turning the monitor back everything is working fine again.

Thanks for pointing me into the right direction without having to reinstall several times... : )